# mysql query does not work

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to set query if row not exist

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM table WHERE id=1)
INSERT INTO table (id, name) VALUES (1,'abx');
```

and that if id!=1 then values are inserted and Check if row already exists

if any solution ?

thanks in advance ...

finally i soved it

INSERT INTO table (id, name) VALUES (1,'abx') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = 1;

thanks for your suport

Answer (score 1):

You have problem with data types - in `SELECT` id is compared to number (`id = 1` - without apostrophes) and in `INSERT` id is written as a string (in apostrophes: `'1'`).

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `table_name` (`id`, `name`)
VALUES (1, 'abx');
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not have "IF NOT EXISTS".

For more info: [How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)

You'll see that there are workarounds, but using MsSQL syntax won't work.

Using `IGNORE` should help: `INSERT IGNORE INTO`

Alternatively, simply let it fail.

Answer (score 0):

I think that:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table (id, name) VALUES (1,'abx');
```

does that you want. It'll fail silently if the `INSERT` was unsuccessful.

Note that the key doesn't need quotes, it's an integer, not a string